# Getting PHP to write clean html

Tags: php

My PHP tends output html in really long, difficult to read html.

If my PHP is written as:

```
<?php 
     echo "<li>";
     echo "<strong>Hello</strong>";
     echo "</li>";
?>
```

it outputs HTML like this

```
<li><strong>Hello</strong></li>
```

which dosnt look that bad, but imagine if thats within a `foreach` loop which out putted variants of that, all on one line..

Is there a way to get my PHP to output as neatly composed HTML ?

Comment: ^^ so make the page larger and slower for no benefit? take a look at google some time, all line breaks removed makes senses, adding them does not.

Comment: @Dagon that's why I didn't put it as an answer. I don't see the point either, but if it's what you wanna do that's how.

Comment: You can use my lib to generate HTML maybe this will help to generate. No need to concat strings anymore: [link](http://htmlbuilder.history-archiv.net) It also uses tab or spaces for indentation.

But be aware, check the bugtracker. There are two little bugs in the current version. A bugfixed one is coming soon with the new release.

Comment: @sam Every modern browser has a builtin set of developer tools (or a plugin/extension, that provides this). All of this developer tools have a fancy html-view :) There is absolutely no need (anymore) to write HTML with intendation and newlines.

Comment: @dagon in the main part it dosnt matter, but when i want to view the source to see how things are being out putted, which i find easier that reading it straight from the php file, its makes it much easier..

Comment: @sam there are tools for that as pointed out already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is: include the whitespace in your output (for example, add `\n` after each tag).

However, doing that is really an exercise in futility. If you want to view the HTML yourself, get an HTML pretty printer (or use the one included in your browser's developer tools). If it's meant for a browser, the browser doesn't care.

Answer (score 1):

Use a template engine like [SMARTY](http://www.smarty.net/). This will allow you to keep all your html in completely different files than your PHP (it does compile as PHP). This will improve the readability of all of your code. You can then format the html any way you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the \n to make a line break.

```
<?php 
     echo "<li>\n";
     echo "<strong>Hello</strong>\n";
     echo "</li>\n";
?>
```

But why use your time on it? Chrome details console will fix it if its because you use the html source as a debug tool.

Answer (score 0):

Whether this is nice or not is subjective, but it works:

```
<?php
    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
    {
?>
<li><strong>Hello</strong></li>
<?php
    }
?>
```

What I'm trying to get at here is that you can go in and out of PHP mode, so if you have long strands of HTML, you can format them as such, instead of `echo`ing everything.